# Alternative for android.graphics.Path

Tags: android, android-canvas

I've been struck hard with an issue with the path class that is used to draw smooth lines on canvas with the `canvas.drawPath(path,paint)` function . Path class is useful for smoothing out lines with the `path.quadTo()` and `cubeTo()` function . But they do not let you draw a smoothed out line with varying thickness . I want to draw a Path on the canvas with increasing thickness up to a certain threshold width and then slim out at the end . Also i tried using a number of paths at every touch point of user but that fails when the user moves his finger really fast , because at that time a single path of a long length is obtained . Please help me i am in big trouble with this . Is there any other way of smoothing out lines .

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the PathMeausre class , where we can easily get subPaths from a prent path and manuplate them accordingly . When i ll be done with the code ,i ll post the snippet soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to vary the width of the `Path` that is drawn using the `canvas.drawPath()` method. The following code snippet should help you regarding that:

```
private Paint myPaint;
myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
myPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
myPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
if(someFlag != thresholdValue)
   myPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
else
   {
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(someReducedValue); // or have a counter updated in your thread to regularly decrement the value
   }

//..

..//

canvas.drawPath(path, myPaint); // inside onDraw() where path corresponds to your Path variable
```